# Get element from JsonNode array

Tags: java, jackson

I have this json:

```
{
    "text":[
        {"a":1},
        {"b":2}
    ]
}
```

I have this code:

```
JsonNode jsonNode = (new ObjectMapper()).readTree(jsonString);

//get first element from "text"
//this is just an explanation of what i want

String aValue = jsonNode.get("text")[0]
                        .get("a")
                        .asText();
```

How I can done that, without mapping it to an object?

Or do something like `JsonNode[] array` and `array[0]` represent `a` and `array[1]` represent `b`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to explicitly traverse through the json and find the value of `a` , you can do it like this for the json that you specified.

```
String aValue = jsonNode.get("text").get(0).get("a").asText();
```

Finding the value of `b` would be

```
String bValue = jsonNode.get("text").get(1).get("b").asText();
```

You can also traverse through the elements within the text array and get the values of `a` and `b` as

```
for (JsonNode node : jsonNode.get("text")) {
    System.out.println(node.fields().next().getValue().asText());
}
```

And that would print the below on the console

```
1
2
```

Comment: I know I can iterate with `for loop`. But I need to get just one element on exact index. `.get(x)` is what I needed. I didn't knew it works on array. Thanks.

Comment: From the Array, I want to get the value of "b", but I don't know the index of that element in the array. How can I achieve it?